# How to Pass data from controller to JavaScript without converting the < " > to < &qout; >

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I have some issues trying to pass dynamic data to chart. I keep on having error when i pass the value from controller to view this is my sample code from controller.

```
    Public ActionResult Index()
    {
      string[] comL = new string[7]; 
      ComP = "Comp1|Comp2|Comp3|Comp4|Comp5|Comp6|Comp7";       
      comL = ComP.Split('|');
      gp.CompanyLoggedIn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comL); 
      return View(gp);
    }
```

This is my model

```
public class gpChart
{
    public string CompanyLoggedIn { get; set; }
    public object UserLoggedIn { get; set; }
    public object LicenseAvail { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code from my view

```
<script>
$(function(){

    //create variables to pass the values dynamically
    var chartype = 'column';
    var chartTitle = 'License available & LogIn Users Monitoring';
    var chartCategories = @Model.CompanyLoggedIn;
    var chartData = '';


    // function is created to pass the value dynamically and be able to refresh the highCharts on every refresh 
    function setDynamicChart(chartype,chartTitle,chartCategories,chartData){

        Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', {

            chart: {
                type: chartype,
                options3d: {
                    enabled: false,
                    alpha: 15,
                    beta: 15,
                    viewDistance: 25,
                    depth: 40
                }
            },

            title: {
                text: chartTitle
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories:  chartCategories,
                labels: {
                    skew3d: true,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '16px'
                    }
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'No. of License/LogIn Users',
                    skew3d: true
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y} / {point.stackTotal}'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    depth: 40
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'License',
                data: @Model.LicenseAvail,
                stack: 'License'
            }, {
                name: 'LogIn',
                data: @Model.UserLoggedIn,
                stack: 'LogIn'

            }]

        });
    }

});
</script>
```

The problem is when the value of variable 'ComP' has double qoute < " > which is normal because the data inside the array is string. However, it is converted to <& quot ;> which gives an error during run time. Does anybody has an idea how to solved this kind of error? below is the screenshot of the actual output of data in JavaScript function.

[actual output of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZU00.png)

Comment: Try `var chartCategories = @Html.Raw(Model.CompanyLoggedIn);` => seems that you need to use raw string instead of directly assigning `Model.CompanyLoggedIn` to JS variable.

Comment: You do not use `gp.CompanyLoggedIn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comL); ` - its `gp.CompanyLoggedIn = comL;` and in the view its `var chartCategories = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CompanyLoggedIn))`